# Google Maps API Key for 127.0.0.1

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've been working with Google Maps for a while in my local development environment (I'm working on `http://127.0.0.1:5000`), but lately I'm getting this error:

```
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html.
```

In my Google API Console I have created an Browser Key, and I've tried the following domains:

```
http://127.0.0.1/*
http://localhost/*
http://127.0.0.1:5000/*
http://0.0.0.0:5000/*
http://*:*/*
```

Obviously, not being about to see the map is making local development quite tricky. But I cannot figure out how to get around this. Can anyone point me at the correct configuration/approach to resolve this?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) doesn't seem to talk about this sort of thing, which isn't helpful.

Comment: Please define **"a while"**. The TOS require a [public accessibility](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1). Although I can't imagine how they be able to identify your application(the referer "localhost" isn't really suitable for that) it may be that your development-phase has been too long and they assume a violation of the policies. However, I would rather assume another issue(maybe you've reached your quota too often). I would start by removing all referers to exclude an issue with the referer.

Comment: I think the issue started in the last 2 weeks due to swapping from Webrick (port 3000) to a Foreman/Unicorn setup (port 5000). If the application *must* be public, how could anyone develop new things? There must be a way of doing this. I've tried creating new keys, with a single referrer, but no luck.

Comment: With "a while" I mean, since when are you developing? Of course it's possible to develop on a local environment, but maybe not for years.

Comment: I don't know, exactly, maybe 4 months or so?

Comment: Try just removing the key, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same trouble, and the issue is to **remove the key param** in the adress as suggested by Mano Marks.

Just change

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Below is a full working code (HTML + JS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reverse Geocoding</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

    </style>
    <style>
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        width: 350px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 225px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
}

function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
  geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```